# CustomAction error with IIS : UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: wix

I get the following exception when I double click my MSI package

```
CustomActionException: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions


   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_SitesSection()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.get_Sites()
...
```

It does this because it's trying to access the path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config from inside a Custom Action

Now if I ran the MSI from PowerShell, where you're running as Administrator, it seems to work fine but the default double-click invocation does not work

Other than adding myself to the UAC of that folder, is there anyway for my CustomActions to run with elevated privileges?

I tried the Package-level attribute of InstallPrivileges="elevated" but to no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Bootstrapper to run the msi in admin mode by default. You can use Wix Bootstrapper to do that. Or you can use any third party tool like [WinZip Self extractor](http://www.winzip.com/win/en/index.htm) or [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to run the msi file. It will run the msi as administrator always.